# Start a telephone on textview click

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a class `TenantDetailsListAdapter` details that extends `BaseAdapter`  as

```
public class TenantDetailsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


}
```

i am trying to start an intent activity insite the class but it is not working.

My intent is as follows :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+text1 .trim()));

startActivity(callIntent);
```

can someone know how to call an activity which is not in an activity extends.

Comment: Do you have permission in manifest for using function of call.

Comment: Try to use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead of ACTION_CALL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do something like this in your `BaseAdapter` :

```
private Context _mContext;
public MyBaseAdapter(Context context/*  some other data you need */){
    this._mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+"+text1 .trim()));
   calIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  // you are starting intent out of the activity so you will need this.
   _mContext.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```